# I would like to set a delay between a set of loops in imacros

Tags: loops, imacros

hi there I would like to set a long delay, eg, 3600seconds between say every 100 loops of my script, may i know if this is possible!

```
 VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
 TAB T=1
 SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
 set !errorignore yes
 SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 0
 SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10
 SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1

 URL GOTO=http://statigr.am/viewer.php
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:searchForm ATTR=ID:getSearch CONTENT=selfie
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:searchForm ATTR=ID:startSearch
 TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:selfie
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:like*
 'pause
 Wait seconds=2
 URL GOTO=http://statigr.am/viewer.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use JS scripting.

```
 //define the macro
 var macro;

 macro="CODE:";

 macro +="VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX"+"\n";
 macro +="TAB T=1"+"\n";
 macro +="SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO"+"\n";
 macro +="set !errorignore yes"+"\n";
 macro +="SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 0"+"\n";
 macro +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10"+"\n";
 macro +="SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1"+"\n";

 macro +="URL GOTO=http://statigr.am/viewer.php"+"\n";
 macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:searchForm ATTR=ID:getSearch CONTENT=selfie"+"\n";
 macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:searchForm ATTR=ID:startSearch"+"\n";
 macro +="TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:selfie"+"\n";
 macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:like*"+"\n";
 macro +="'pause"+"\n";
 macro +="Wait seconds=2"+"\n";
 macro +="URL GOTO=http://statigr.am/viewer.php"+"\n";


 //loop the macro 
 for(var i=1;i<=1000;i++)
 {

 //play macro
 iimPlay(macro)

 //after 100 loops pause for 3600 seconds
 if(macro%100==0)
 {

 iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=3600")

 }


 }
```